# Permission denied for gitlab-runner

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have been trying to run the CI job in Gitlab using my newly created Gitlab runner as shell executor, however my job fails right away with the following output:

```
$ apt-get --quiet update --yes
Reading package lists...
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

I have checked that job runs under gitlab-runnner user, and I have tried to edit sudoers file in the following fashion

```
# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
gitlab-runner ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
gitlab-runner ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

However nothing has helped, when I try to check the execution of the command right on gitlab runner without ci job:

```
sudo -u gitlab-runner apt-get --quiet update --yes
Reading package lists...
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

Comment: Have you tried simply `sudo apt update -y` ?

Answer (score 0):

before_script:

- apt update -y # THIS LINE FIXED IT - thanks to sytech
- apt-get install -qq git
- "which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install -qq openssh-client )"
- eval $(ssh-agent -s)
- ssh-add <(cat "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
- mkdir -p ~/.ssh
- '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'